# Initializing a member of type array in a superclass, using the initialization list of a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, initialization-list

How can I initialize an array that belongs to a superclass? I want to set all the values of the superclass's array in the initialization list of my subclass.

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string arr_[3];
    Foo(std::string arr[3])
    :arr_(arr)
    {  
    }

};

class PersonEntity : public Foo 
{
public:
    PersonEntity(Person person)
    :Foo(
    {
        {"any string"},
        {"any string"},
        {"any string"}
    })

    {
    }
};
```

Comment: You need a colon `:` not a comma `,` before `Foo`.

Comment: Thank you. That's true. But it's not the solution ;-(

Comment: That is probably because `Foo`'s constructor parameter is a pointer. But you should post an MCVE.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] and show your errors verbatim.

Comment: What if you take the parameter by reference? `std::string (&arr)[3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main error is in your base class, because raw arrays cannot be passed by value. Just use `std::array` to get appropriate value semantics.

In your derived class, there are too many curly braces. You don't need the inner ones.

Here is a fixed version (I've also removed the `Person` parameter which seems completely unrelated to the question):

```
#include <array>
#include <string>

struct Foo
{
    std::array<std::string, 3> arr;
    Foo(std::array<std::string, 3> const& arr) : arr(arr)
    {  
    }

};

class PersonEntity : public Foo 
{
public:
    PersonEntity()
    : Foo( { "any string", "any string", "any string" } )
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that `std::array<T, int>` was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @iksemyonov: I don't know. I used to explicitly mention this, but we're in 2016 already. That's five years from 2011. Compilers support C++11 by default. And Stackoverflow is definitely one of the places where one should try to push new technologies and advance C++ in general. So today I generally just assume that C++11 is available, just as people 10-20 years ago came to accept the fact that compilers with exception support, a working standard-library implementation or RTTI had become the rule.

Comment: I most probably say this based on the fact that at school, where these simple question arrive from, C++11 may be forbidden just like any advanced practice that allows students to skip learning the essentials using convenience functionality instead. And, also, from the fact that we were never taught C++11 even after year 2011.

Comment: @iksemyonov: Fair enough, but it's not how I'd teach C++, and I choose to fight what I consider bad teaching practices.

Comment: Anyway it's good that we can learn some modern C++ on SO. Being ready to stand up for your POV is great as well